# LCD interfacing with ARM cortex M0+ lpc845

Tags: c, arm, embedded, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to interface 8x2 lcd using parallel interfacing[4 bit mode],
Display used - 8x2 lcd [PC 0802--A]
ST7066U--Dot Matrix LCD Controller/Driver

Since i'm trying to interface using GPIO pins, not using I2C or SPI
interface, and since no drivers are there for this particular MCU[LPC845],
I compared with lpc2148 MCU [lcd.c and lcd.h files], and have made the changes, but not able to write to the display.

And when checked the data/command signals in the oscilloscope, in data pins
I'm getting float voltages[i.e., for d4-D7] LOW signal on this pins, and 
high signals on command pins[RS,RW,EN].

Kindly suggest me the process of writing the char/string to the display varies for ARM mcu?as i'm referring lpc2148 libraries.

Thank you

Comment: Handle your problem step by step. Since you already have oscilloscope and can verify it easily - write simple code to set your desired pins as outputs and make sure you know how to set them to 0 or 1. Later write code to handle LCD or whatever device you want.